# What should params,progress,result of this AsyncTask be

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to find the current location of the android device by clicking a button. Geocoder hangs the UI when ran in the UIThread so I have to run it on a background thread. I am new to AsyncTasks. So far I have this line of code, but I have literally no idea what the params,progress,result must be. I don't want anything to enter, or no progress, just the result to be a string that presents the current address.

Thank you in advance.

```
    public void onClickGetCCity(View v){
    new GetCurrentCity.execute();
    }  
       private class GetCurrentCity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{



        @Override
                protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROV

IDER);
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                if(Geocoder.isPresent()){

                    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        if(addresses != null) {
                            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);

                            for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                           strReturnedAddress = (returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameterized type is the input into doInBackground(). The second is the input to onProgressUpdate(). The third is the input to onPostExecute(). You need not use all of them (meaning you can leave one or more of them as Void).

The javadoc for this class has an example that explains how this all works: [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

The third type parameter should be `String`. So the signature of `doInBackground` is:

```
public String doInBackground(Void... params)
```

After you get the address string, return it from `doInBackground`:

```
return strReturnedAddress;
```

Implement the method `onPostExecute(String result)`. Since it runs on the UI thread, you can show the result in a `TextView` or a toast message.